# How do I make a batch file select a random label?

Tags: batch-file

I wish to make a batch file that in one section selects from a label either ":A", ":B", or :C", then goto that label.
I have no idea how to make it select a random label, let alone from that list

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure you accept the answer if it solves the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

```
set /a num=%random% %% 3
if %num%==0 goto A
if %num%==1 goto B
if %num%==2 goto C
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the random number as part of the label

```
set /a num=%random% %% 3
goto :label%num%

:label0
echo Label0
exit /b 

:label1
echo Label1
exit /b 

:label2
echo Label2
exit /b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "alfa=ABC"
SET /A rd=%RANDOM% %%3
set "char=!alfa:~%rd%,1!"
echo Random jump to %char%
goto :%char%
echo line not printed
:A
echo label A
goto :eof
:B
echo label B
goto :eof
:C
echo label C
goto :eof
```